# How to Duplicate Column in same table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm pretty basic with SQL and need help with the following task:

I already have a table with data in it. What I would like to do is to Duplicate a Column (Including the data) in the same table but with a different column name. Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the new column to the table as nullable, either with **SQL Server Management Studio** by right clicking on the Table and clicking "Design" **or** by using an `ALTER TABLE` statement like this `ALTER TABLE TableName ADD NewColumnName DataType NULL`.

Then you can `UPDATE` that new column from the old column like so:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET NewColumnName = OldColumnName
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on other requirements, you might be able to get away with using a computed column. This assumes you don't need to manipulate the data in the duplicated column.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.t
    ADD NewColumn AS OldColumn;
```